# PostgreSQL trigger update with multiple if conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I added this. However, I've no idea why it's not working.
I updated `member_no` on `customers` table, not updating it on `customer_tracking` table.
I've tried it by updating `premember_no`, `email` as well. But it's the same.

```
drop function if exists update_customer_tracking_on_customer_update() cascade;
drop trigger if exists update_customer_tracking_on_customer_update on customers cascade;

create function update_customer_tracking_on_customer_update() returns trigger
    language plpgsql
as
$$
begin
    if new.email != old.email then
        update customer_tracking set email = new.email where customer_tracking.customer_id = new.customer_id;
    end if;
    if new.member_no != old.member_no then
        update customer_tracking set member_no = new.member_no where customer_tracking.customer_id = new.customer_id;
    end if;
    if new.premember_no != old.premember_no then
        update customer_tracking
        set premember_no = new.premember_no
        where customer_tracking.customer_id = new.customer_id;
    end if;
    return new;
end;
$$;

-- auto-generated definition
create trigger update_cust_tracking_on_cust_update_trigger
    after update
    on customers
    for each row
execute procedure update_customer_tracking_on_customer_update();
```

However, if I have a separate function for each column, it all works fine. However, I don't want to have so many triggers. Is it possible to have everything in one function?

Comment: You code is working. customer_tracking will be synced with customers table. see: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_15&fiddle=d0be54d5f295ef4f7d9c81e80d1ff51b

Comment: It should work. I don't schema qualification of either the table name in the trigger or the function used. Are you sure the trigger is being attached to correct table and is using the correct version of function? Maybe throw a [RAISE NOTICE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RAISE) into the function and then check the Postgres logs to see if it is being run.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose here seems how to keep the `customer_tracking` table in sync with the `customer` table. Often times, and always from a maintenance perspective, the best approach is *no additional code at all*. That is the case here: drop the `customer_tracking` table, drop the trigger function  and create a `customer_tracking` view.

```
drop table customer_tracking; 
drop function update_customer_tracking_on_customer_update() cascade;

create or replace view customer_tracking as 
    select customer_id 
         , email
         , member_number
         , premember_no
      from customers;
```

See comparative [example here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=3b55930ae206d02639320d79930feafe).

Comment: Hi Belayer, thank you for your suggestion. I did get to know about which wasn't aware of. The purpose is to keep some database in the customer tracking table even after the user deletes his info from customers table. I see that with view I can't do that.

Comment: No. But you could archive that data when a customer deleted their info (perhaps even with a delete trigger). And still have the advantage of not syncing tables (which inevitably get out of sync).   Further keeping the tracking data in the same table means you loose referential integrity. Another possibility just logically delete the customer data.